# How can I obtain complete context in my custom keyboard in UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm building a custom keyboard using UIKit to obtain the complete context and send it to my backend. In order to obtain the complete context, I have to move the cursor to the end of the context. Therefore, I created a function for that purpose.

```
    func moveCursor() {
        let p = controller.textDocumentProxy
        let contextCount = p.documentContext?.count ?? 0
        let beforeInputCount = p.documentContextBeforeInput?.count ?? 0
        p.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: contextCount - beforeInputCount)
    }
```

However, I have to call the function multiple times, such as after each period, question mark, etc., in order to move the cursor to the end of the sentence.

For example, the text below requires me to call the function twice to move the cursor to the end of the sentence.

```
Hello, how are you? Where are you from? //Since there are 2 question marks, I need to call the function twice.
```

I created a button for testing:

```
Button("moveCursor") {
   moveCursor()
   moveCursor()
}
```

As you can see in my code, even though I called the moveCursor function twice, I still have to click the button twice in order to move to the second question mark. How can I achieve the desired outcome?

[uitextdocumentproxy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextdocumentproxy)